# Calculate the minimum singular vector of row space of large thin matrix

Tags: matrices, svd, linear-algebra

I have $A$, a $n \times 3$ matrix, where $n$ is huge. I want the minimum singular value and its singular vector of row space. I don't want to calculate the eigenvector of $A^TA$.

Comment: Why not? $\mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A$ is only $3 \times 3$.

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer or even how to add to the comment @Rodrigo has already posted: there doesn't seem to be a real question here.  Are you sure you have typed exactly the question you intended to ask?